# Jq adding extra double quotation marks when parsing with AWS Secrets Manager

Tags: json, linux, amazon-web-services, jq, aws-cli

My secrets are stored in AWS Secrets Manager in the following format:

```
KEY_1   "XXXX"
KEY_2   0
```

I am trying to retrieve the secrets in the following format:

```
KEY_1="XXXX"
KEY_2=0
```

that means the same way they're stored in Secrets Manager with `=` symbol. I am using `jq` to parse in the following manner:

```
aws secretsmanager get-secret-value --secret-id <secret_name> --output text --query SecretString \
| jq  -r 'to_entries[] | [.key, "=", "\"", .value, "\"" ] | @tsv' \
| tr -d "\t"
```

This command is working fine but with a small problem. This command is adding an extra double quotation mark (`""`) in the `value` field. It is giving the following output:

```
 KEY_1=""XXXX""
 KEY_2="0"
```

But I do not want these extra double quotation marks to be added. I want the output should be in the same format as described above while retrieving above i.e, without extra quotation marks.

Comment: Drop `"\""`s then. I really don't understand what's being asked here; is this a JQ question or an AWS one?

Comment: @oguzismail thanks it worked, it's an AWS question which requires parsing through `jq`. Actually I am not getting the correct `jq` syntax.

Answer (score 1):

You are outputting as text, what is the need for jq ?

**--output text**

If you want to output as json you can use

**--output json**